# Why does metasploit SSL scanner only show highest version available?

Tags: tls, apache, metasploit

I'm trying to scan my server (Apache2 on Debian), which is configured to support only TLS1.2 (and 1.3, presumably?).  The config line is:

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv3 -TLSv1 -TLSv1.1
```

I scan it with:

```
msf6 > use auxiliary/scanner/ssl/ssl_version
msf6 auxiliary(scanner/ssl/ssl_version) > set RHOSTS my-server.com
msf6 auxiliary(scanner/ssl/ssl_version) > run
```

No surprises there, metasploit reports:

```
[+] server-IP:443         - Connected with SSL Version: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
.... certificate information (it's a Let's Encrypt up-to-date cert)
[+] server-IP:443         - Connected with SSL Version: TLSv1.2, Cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
[+] server-IP:443         - Connected with SSL Version: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
[+] server-IP:443         - Connected with SSL Version: TLSv1.2, Cipher: DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
[+] server-IP:443         - Connected with SSL Version: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
[+] server-IP:443         - Connected with SSL Version: TLSv1.2, Cipher: DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256
[+] server-IP:443         - Connected with SSL Version: TLSv1.2, Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
[+] server-IP:443         - Connected with SSL Version: TLSv1.2, Cipher: DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256
[+] server-IP:443         - Connected with SSL Version: TLSv1.2, Cipher: AES256-GCM-SHA384
[+] server-IP:443         - Connected with SSL Version: TLSv1.2, Cipher: AES128-GCM-SHA256
[+] server-IP:443         - Connected with SSL Version: TLSv1.2, Cipher: AES256-SHA256
[+] server-IP:443         - Connected with SSL Version: TLSv1.2, Cipher: AES128-SHA256
[*] my-server.com:443     - Scanned 1 of 1 hosts (100% complete)
[*] Auxiliary module execution completed
```

Then, on my server I remove the `-TLSv1 -TLSv1.1` from `ssl.conf` (leaving the config line as `SSLProtocol all -SSLv3`), and restart the service (`sudo systemctl restart apache2.service`).

I re-run the metasploit scan, and it reports exactly the same (it only shows connections with TLSv1.2).

I guess my question is:  is it that my server only accepts TLS 1.2? (if so, why?)  Or is it that metasploit only scans using TLS 1.2? (if so, why? the variable `SSLVersion` is set to `All`)

Comment: Did you read the manual or the help text for `ssl_scanner` on how to select the version to test?

Comment: Do you mean this part of the output to `show info`? `SSLVersion  All              yes       SSL version to test (Accepted: All, SSLv3, TLSv1.0, TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3)`

Comment: If so, I guess I should have mentioned in the OP that setting that variable to _anything_ other than `All` (including setting it to `TLSv1.2`) gives me an error: `Auxiliary failed: NoMethodError undefined method 'map' for "TLSv1.2":String`

Comment: Did you try `TLSv1.0`? The options are in the code: https://github.com/rapid7/metasploit-framework/blob/master/modules/auxiliary/scanner/ssl/ssl_version.rb

Comment: I did try that one (`set SSLVersion TLSv1.0` → `SSLVersion => TLSv1.0` ... then: `run` → `Auxiliary failed: NoMethodError undefined method 'map' for "TLSv1.0":String`  (I see the check for BEAST and deprecated access to TLS 1.0 in the code, but I'm not sure where's the discrepancy)

Comment: reinstall metasploit?

Comment: What happens when you change the Apache config to `-TLSv1.2` [i.e. disable 1.2]?

Comment: As you can see from the code, it's all supposed to work, but with some limitations, as you can see. I think what you are seeing is not the intended output, and you are in troubleshooting mode.

Comment: _"-TLSv1.2 to disable 1.2"_ — interesting suggestion!  the metasploit run now outputs nothing (well, it outputs the "100% complete .... " at the end).  Anyway, I tried a Live Kali image (just downloaded), and the output/behaviour is exactly the same. It would seem, as surprising as that looks, like that particular code in MS is buggy?

Comment: I would likely conclude the same.

Comment: Is there any other tool that would allow me to achieve this goal?  With `curl`, I see command-line switches `--tlsvXX` but they're describe as `Use protocol version XX or above`, and the `--sslvXX` are even worse: they're there to be ignored (literally, the command responds with `Warning: Ignores instruction to use SSLv3` and then proceeds! LOL)

Comment: I guess I could go back to some Firefox version from way back for which the highest version supported is TLS 1.1 (and then earlier with support up to TLS 1.0, and so on) and try with those.  However, is there an easier way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40557031/command-prompt-to-check-tls-version-required-by-a-host

Comment: D'oh!  I should have suspected that good'old command-line OpenSSL would do the trick (for some reason, I was thinking that one would have to manually implement the given protocol based on the primitives provided by OpenSSL ..... not sure why I thought that would be the case!!)